# Besides checking /boot/config_xx and /proc/config.gz, how to confirm the preempt rt option is enabled or not for a specific Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, preempt-rt

Besides checking /boot/config_xx and /proc/config.gz, how to confirm the preempt rt option is enabled or not for a specific Linux kernel?

I can login to the OS by SSH and I have the root permission.

Answer (score 1):

At command line you can do `uname -a`, that should show something like this.

```
~$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.35-rt39-v7l+ #2 SMP PREEMPT_RT Thu May 13 02:26:47 PDT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
~$
```

Then you can look up at top of the ssh window and see the same thing (palm slap to forehead is optional):

```
symetrix@192.168.2.45's password:
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.35-rt39-v7l+ #2 SMP PREEMPT_RT Thu May 13 02:26:47 PDT 2021 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software; ...
```

String PREEMPT_RT (rather than just PREEMPT or other such scheduler terms) tells what is up.